# Custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout not working

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to do a **custom Flow Layout** similar to the Apple News app. The `flowLayout.delegate = self` is in the `viewDidLoad()` method while my networking code is in in an `async` method in the `viewDidAppear()`.
The problem is that the methods for the custom flow Layout get called before I can retrieve all the data from the server, therefore the app crashes.
Any ideas on how I could make it work? Here's my `ViewController` implementation:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, AppleNewsFlowLayoutDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var flowLayout: AppleNewsFlowLayout!

    var newsArray = [News]()
    var getFromDb = GetFromDb()

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if getFromDb.news.isEmpty {
            loadStore()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        flowLayout.delegate = self
    }

    func loadStore() {
        let urlString = "https://url"
        self.getFromDb.getBreaksFromDb(url: urlString) { (breaksDataCell) in
            if !breaksDataCell.isEmpty {
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return getFromDb.news.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        // Filling the cells with the correct info...
        return cell
    }

func AppleNewsFlowLayout(_ AppleNewsFlowLayout: AppleNewsFlowLayout, cellTypeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NewsCellType {
    return getFromDb.news[indexPath.row].cellType
}
```

}

> Here below the struct for News:

```
struct News {
let image: String
let provider: String
let title: String
let cellType: NewsCellType

init(image: String, provider: String, title: String, cellType: NewsCellType) {
    self.image = image
    self.provider = provider
    self.title = title
    self.cellType = cellType
}}
```

> **The Flow Layout class**:

```
protocol AppleNewsFlowLayoutDelegate: class {
    func AppleNewsFlowLayout(_ AppleNewsFlowLayout: AppleNewsFlowLayout, cellTypeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NewsCellType
}

class AppleNewsFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    var maxY: CGFloat = 0.0
    var isVSetOnce = false
    weak var delegate: AppleNewsFlowLayoutDelegate?
    var attributesArray: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?

    private var numberOfItems:Int{
        return (collectionView?.numberOfItems(inSection: 0))!
    }

    override func prepare() {
        for item in 0 ..< numberOfItems{
            super.prepare()
            minimumLineSpacing = 10
            minimumInteritemSpacing = 16
            sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 16, bottom: 10, right: 16)
        }
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        guard let newsType: NewsCellType = delegate?.AppleNewsFlowLayout(self, cellTypeForItemAt: indexPath) else {
            fatalError("AppleNewsFlowLayoutDelegate method is required.")
        }

        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
        var x = sectionInset.left
        maxY = maxY + minimumLineSpacing

        switch newsType {

        case .big:
            let width = screenWidth - sectionInset.left - sectionInset.right
            attributes.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: maxY, width: width, height: width * 1.2)
            maxY += width * 1.2

        case .horizontal:
            let width = screenWidth - sectionInset.left - sectionInset.right
            attributes.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: maxY, width: width, height: 150)
            maxY += 150

        case .vertical:
            let width = (screenWidth - minimumInteritemSpacing - sectionInset.left - sectionInset.right) / 2
            x = isVSetOnce ? x + width + minimumInteritemSpacing : x
            maxY = isVSetOnce ? maxY-10 : maxY
            attributes.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: maxY, width: width, height: screenWidth * 0.8)
            if isVSetOnce {
                maxY += screenWidth * 0.8
            }
            isVSetOnce = !isVSetOnce
        }
        return attributes
    }


    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: maxY)
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        if attributesArray == nil {
            attributesArray = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
            print(collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) - 1)
            for i in 0 ... collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) - 1
            {
                let attributes = self.layoutAttributesForItem(at: IndexPath(item: i, section: 0))
                attributesArray!.append(attributes!)
            }
        }
        return attributesArray
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `getFromDb.news` a force-unwrapped Optional?

Comment: Copy the Xcode's crash info to here.

Comment: Like @NRitH said, getFromDb.news might be nil. Init it in class GetFromDb may avoid the crash.

Comment: I believe the crash is caused from the cellForItemAt indexPath method. You are returning a cell however you don’t seem to have registers or declared and cells.

Comment: No, GetFromDb is not nil, but it returns the response only after the loadStore() method is complete. That is the problem, because the AppleNewsFlowLayout method gets triggered right away when getFromDb.news is still nil.

Comment: It all works perfectly if I hard code the data. But when I retrieve the data from the database, the async method creates the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things which you need to do when we deal with custom collection view flow layouts.

**changes in prepare() method in custom flow layout**. you will start preparing the layout only if the number of items more than 0.

```
private var numberOfItems:Int{
    return (collectionView?.numberOfItems(inSection: 0))!
}

override func prepare() {
        for item in 0 ..< numberOfItems{ }
}
```

use **numberOfItems** property whenever you wanted to do something with collectionView items in the customFlowLayout to avoid crashes.

Comment: `numberOfItemsInSection` should just `return getFromDB.news.count ?? 0`. No need for the verbosity.

Comment: You should use nil coalescing operator only with the optionals. Otherwise, you will get a warning. "Left side of nil coalescing operator '??' has non-optional type 'Int', so the right side is never used". Check this. As I do not know what the type of the news, I have provided the solutions for all possible things.

Comment: Yes, but not if the left-hand side is an explicitly-unwrapped Optional, which is what I asked OP `getFromDB.news` is, and which subsequent comments to OP's post suggest that it was.

Comment: Hi @Kumar Reddy, it gives me the following error: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[News]'

Comment: I am adding the struct for News to better explain how I built it

Comment: Please find the updated code.. This is miscommunication is because of I am not aware your struct structure.

Comment: Let me know if you face any erros.. Mark it as answer if it is working for you.

Comment: it is still crashing.. on the Flow Layout, maybe I should post that class as well so that you can see it

Comment: Yes please...and let me know where it is crashing. You can do that by enabling Exception Breakpoint.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160979/discussion-between-giovanni-and-kumar-reddy).

Comment: Weird, still not displaying the collectionView because UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes is nil

Comment: Let us chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160979/discussion-between-giovanni-and-kumar-reddy

Answer (score 0):

Here below the functioning clean code if you are looking to implement a Custom Collection View Flow Layout similar to the Apple News app with networking:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, AppleNewsFlowLayoutDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var flowLayout: AppleNewsFlowLayout!
var getFromDb = GetFromDb()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if getFromDb.news.isEmpty {
        loadStore()
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    flowLayout.delegate = self
}


func loadStore() {
    let urlString = "https://yourURL"
    self.getFromDb.getBreaksFromDb(url: urlString) { (breaksDataCell) in
        if !breaksDataCell.isEmpty {
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
                print("RELOAD")
            })
        }
    }
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return getFromDb.news.count
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let news = getFromDb.news[indexPath.row]
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: news.cellType.rawValue, for: indexPath) as! NewCell
    cell.image.image = UIImage(named: "news")!
    cell.provider.text = news.provider
    cell.title.text = news.title

    return cell
}


func AppleNewsFlowLayout(_ AppleNewsFlowLayout: AppleNewsFlowLayout, cellTypeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NewsCellType {
    print(getFromDb.news[indexPath.row].cellType)
    return getFromDb.news[indexPath.row].cellType
}
}
```

This is the Flow Layout class:

```
protocol AppleNewsFlowLayoutDelegate: class {
func AppleNewsFlowLayout(_ AppleNewsFlowLayout: AppleNewsFlowLayout, cellTypeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NewsCellType
}

class AppleNewsFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
var maxY: CGFloat = 0.0
var isVSetOnce = false
weak var delegate: AppleNewsFlowLayoutDelegate?
var attributesArray: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?
private var cache = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

private var numberOfItems:Int{
    return (collectionView?.numberOfItems(inSection: 0))!
}

override func prepare() {
    super.prepare()

        minimumLineSpacing = 10
        minimumInteritemSpacing = 16
        sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 16, bottom: 10, right: 16)

        guard cache.isEmpty == true, let collectionView = collectionView else {
            return
        }

        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        var x = sectionInset.left
        maxY = maxY + minimumLineSpacing

        for item in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)
            guard let newsType: NewsCellType = delegate?.AppleNewsFlowLayout(self, cellTypeForItemAt: indexPath) else {
                fatalError("AppleNewsFlowLayoutDelegate method is required.")
            }
            let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)

            switch newsType {

            case .big:
                let width = screenWidth - sectionInset.left - sectionInset.right
                attributes.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: maxY, width: width, height: width * 1.2)
                maxY += width * 1.2

            case .horizontal:
                let width = screenWidth - sectionInset.left - sectionInset.right
                attributes.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: maxY, width: width, height: 150)
                maxY += 150

            case .vertical:
                let width = (screenWidth - minimumInteritemSpacing - sectionInset.left - sectionInset.right) / 2
                x = isVSetOnce ? x + width + minimumInteritemSpacing : x
                maxY = isVSetOnce ? maxY-10 : maxY
                attributes.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: maxY, width: width, height: screenWidth * 0.8)
                if isVSetOnce {
                    maxY += screenWidth * 0.8
                }
                isVSetOnce = !isVSetOnce
            }
            cache.append(attributes)
        }
}

override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    var layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
    for attribute in cache{
        if attribute.frame.intersects(rect){
            layoutAttributes.append(attribute)
        }
    }
    return layoutAttributes
}


override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    return cache[indexPath.item]
}


override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: maxY)
}
}
```